# How can a show row number from 1 to so on in a listview in xamarin forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, row-number

I have got a requirement where I have to create a listView which adds item number with each item. I have got an idea of putting a number in model of item but I am unable to figure that out.

Comment: How far have you gotten? Can you share what you you do have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way should be to add one additional property `Index` to the `ViewModel` that is bound to the the `ListView.ItemsSource` and then simply represent it on the screen.

Alternatively, if there is a need to use an enumerated `ListView` multiple times you could create a reusable control and move the logic from the `ViewModel` to the `UI` layer.

So it all depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I used the first suggestion. Added  a property in Model and shown it in the list.