# Add Serial Number against ListView Items in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, listviewitem

I have used RepeaterView and Bound the ItemSource to  List

```
<local:RepeaterView ItemsSource="{Binding Approvals}">
   <local:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                 <ViewCell>
                 <StackLayout>
                     ........
                 </StackLayout>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
    </local:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
</local:RepeaterView>
```

This is the List Type Property

```
private List<ApprovalVM> _Approvals;
    public List<ApprovalVM> Approvals
    {
        get { return _Approvals; }
        set { SetValue(ref _Approvals, value); }
    }
```

I want to show Item serial number in a column in this ListView
Like this
[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI9Lk.png)

Comment: when you say "serial number" do you really mean "sequential index", like 1,2,3,4...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a show row number from 1 to so on in a listview in xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335049/how-can-a-show-row-number-from-1-to-so-on-in-a-listview-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: "Serial Number" typically does not mean the same thing as "index number", so your use of that term is very confusing

Comment: My Question is same but i didnt get my answer from that question.My RepeaterView.ItemSource is already bound to a list property,
and in that answer he is asking to bind that property to index (new)property.

Comment: the answers provided in that question should apply to your scenario also - either add a property to your VM, or create a custom control that will handle it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create another list to add serial no property.

```
    class Temp { 
    public List<ApprovalVM> Approvals{get;set;} 
    public int SerialNo{get;set;}
}
```

then create list of Temp and add item one by one & increase your SerialNo.
And bind SerialNo in your RepeaterView design.